# In JMeter, "Save Responses to a File", how can I increment the file name while attaching a custom suffix to the end of the file names

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter, when using "Save Responses to a File" to store http responses, how can I increment the file name while attaching a custom suffix to the end of the file names?
Here was my scenario

1. Recorded http traffic of a file conversion and download from a web site using the Recording Controller and HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.
2. I then moved this recorded traffic from the Recording Controller up to my main Thread Group.  This allowed me to rerun what I had recorded.
3. Then, I add a "Save Responses to a file" to the HTTP Request sampler for the "download" action that I had recorded from the web site.

However, I had trouble with the filename incrementing at the end of the file like this:

```
testFile.txt1
testFile.txt2
testFile.txt3
```

I wanted this:

```
testFile1.txt
testFile2.txt
testFile3.txt
```

Also, if I did not uncheck "Don't add suffix", then "octet-stream" was my file type, which is not what I wanted:

```
testFile1.octet-stream
testFile2.octet-stream
testFile3.octet-stream
```

So, how can I properly increment the file name with the correct file extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using [__counter()](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/64307-using-jmeter-functions-part-ii) function which can be either virtual-user-specific or global as follows:

`testFile${__counter(FALSE,)}.txt` - for GLOBAL counter
`testFile${__counter(TRUE,)}.txt` -  for SEPARATE counter per Virtual User

Comment: I think both ways work ( the one I listed and this one ).  However, this seems a little more efficient and also allows for the Global option if needed, which I did need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by doing the following:

1. Right clicked on the HTTP Request I wanted to add the counter and chose Add -> Config Element -> Counter
2. Set "1" for "Start" and 1 for "Increment".
3. Named the Counter with the "Reference Name" of "counter"
4. In the "Save Responses to a file" mentioned above for the "download" traffic, I put "filename${counter}.xxx" for "Filename prefix:" where xxx is the file extension
5. Still in the "Save Responses to a file", I also checked the boxes for both "Don't add number to prefix" and "Don't add suffix"

   - I forgot to mention that, for my "Thread Group", I had set "Number of Threads(users)" to "5" and "Loop Count" to 3.  This would give me 15 users.

So, keeping that in mind, my files were named all correctly from:

testFile1.txt
testFile2.txt
.
.
.
testFile15.txt

Hope this helps someone as I struggled with this for a little bit :-).